# Converting 1-5Hz from linear generator into 60Hz

Tags: power-electronics, generator

My senior design project is a linear wind generator that's modeled after the *Wind Vortex Project*.

I've been looking for a way to internally increase the frequency of my generation subsystem from my range of 1-5Hz to 60Hz so I don't run into any saturation issues with my transformer's 60Hz frequency rating. So far I've noticed the saturation is definitely prevalent, the waveforms are nice and clean before the transformer and after they show clear signs of saturation.  I've had a few thoughts on how to go about solving this issue.

The first would be to completely redesign the induction generator to scale the voltage to the frequency. However this would be fairly expensive to do and I'm sitting with only about 220 dollars left in my budget. I wish I would have known about this prior to the initial design.

The second thought and my question is could I potentially use a VFD or DC to AC inverter to up the frequency from the 1-5Hz range to 60Hz and then send it to the transformer? I remembered the concept of VFD's and DC to AC inverters from my power electronics class a few semesters ago, and did some looking around and found that most of them are made for 50-60Hz or vice versa for frequency converters. Would this even be feasible for such low frequency? If it's viable is there any specific type of VFDs or DC to AC inverters already made for this specific type of low frequency application?

Comment: Consider converting it to DC then back to 60Hz AC. You could put a battery in the middle to smooth out surges etc. Without knowing the power and voltage involved this is my best guess.

Comment: it's a fairly low power system. more information: at 1-5Hz voltage ranges from 2.8-7.1V and current ranges  from 180-330mA. The reason for the transformer is mainly just to reduce rectification losses and ease with mechanical complexity.

Comment: @RyanakaDragin I'm gathering that the idea of a change in gearing ratios to the generator, and therefore a different generator too, is beyond the budget. If so, then see what you can find from energy harvester ICs designed for low frequency (wind) inputs. I haven't attempted a search. But I suspect that if you are diligent about it, you will find a few good hits on the topic. Perhaps something that can come within your budget. (I gather that you are roughly speaking about 1 W of generation.) You might consider a chopper of some kind, too. Interesting problem, though.

Comment: its a good idea with such a question to state the generator specs on Power, + Impedance , and time, & frequency characteristics.  It's obviously low inertia and very unstable ,rather more like brown noise in that spectral range. Is is moving coil or moving magnet? I would expect to use a conjugate impedance matched MPPT dual converter with full bridges. Please make a list of all specs in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1-5 Hz is nearly DC. It's unlikely that a practical transformer could be of use to convert it.

One idea: rectify the windmill AC to DC, then use an inverter to step up the DC to 60Hz AC. That might be possible with low-cost components.

If you're concerned about diode losses (who isn't?), consider a technique called *synchronous rectification*. With synchronous rectification, the diodes are replaced by FET switches that are driven actively in sync with the input waveform, so there is no Vf drop.

There's also some things to be done at the alternator itself to make your life easier:

- increase the rotation speed through gearing or belt
- increase the number of poles
- increase the winding count (output higher voltage)

Doing these together could yield a solution you could work with using transformers, with less concern about diode IR drops.

Comment: Unfortunately increasing the speed is a no go with my teams design for the mechanical section. Also, we're not allowed to use rotational generation at all so it makes finding information on it hard. The number of poles assuming it's what I think(adding more coils) would just be more expensive. The mechanical to electrical conversion system as it stands right now works by translating a mechanical push in the x y direction on a rail road like type of track pushing a magnet across two 1100 turn coils with a carbon steel plate core(Cheaper than silicon steel) per quadrant(there is four).

Comment: I think the DC to AC conversion with an inverter  is probably the best method due to the various losses already from eddy currents in the generator itself that can best optimize the system. If I had a much bigger budget I could really go wild.